# Azure WP app service - I want to clone my website

Tags: database, wordpress, azure, saas

I have a WP website running on Azure app service, I want to clone it because my website is online but I want to experiment on it (So I want to clone it, leave one online and experiment with the clone), There is a service to clone my app inside azure but it is paid, it is there other way to clone the content (plugins and configuration) of my wp app service to put it in another wp app service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different options you can use to copy your site;

**1) Copy the files and database onto the new webspace**
This method is good if you have access to all your files and the database for your site. You simply copy the files over to the other webspace and export the database. This link will give you more information on this method - https://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/

**2) Using a plugin to do it for you**
There are several plugins you can use that will do the above for you and will automatically create a backup of your site including the database so that you don't have to do anything. Might I suggest this plugin, I've used it myself so I know it's reliable and should do the trick - https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/
It also has a feature that allows you to change any old URLs to the new URL which will save you a bit of time.

I hope this provides enough information for you to successfully transfer your site over.

Comment: Sorry the very late answer, still, there you have your point, it worked, thx.